# Canvas redraw not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an Elevator class that is used for objects, and I put them in an array.
However my Prepare function that clears the canvas works for everything else on screen except for this object. I have tried moving around the resrawing functions and where I call them but nothing seems to fix it, and I don't see what the others are affected if this object isn't?

click and see what I mean:
http://www.taffatech.com/Platformer.html

```
function drawElevators()
{

for (var i=0;i<Elevators.length;i++)
{ 

Elevators[i].y--;
ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.fillRect(Elevators[i].x,Elevators[i].y,Elevators[i].width,Elevators[i].height);


}


}
```

My Loop:

```
function Loop(){

Prepare();
movePlayer();   

if(level == 1)
{
Level1();
}

else if(level == 2)
{
Level2();
}

else if (Level ==3)
{
Level3();
}

else
{
Level4;
}


 if(ElevatorOn == true)
  {
   drawElevators();
  }

checkCol();
drawPlayer();



requestAnimFrame(Loop);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many elevators which are all close together, and they spawn infinitely.
The Prepare() function works and is not at fault here.

Try adding this to limit the number of elevators:

```
function Level1()
{
    ...
    var Ele1 = new Elevator(canvasWidth - (canvasWidth - 90),canvasHeight - 50,40,20);
    if(Elevators.length<2){
        Elevators.push(Ele1);
    ....
}
```

Comment: But I only created one elevator object so what if I wanted more than 1 elevator per level? How can I make it so the object just rises(y--) and then redraw the object?

Comment: You are already re-drawing the object. But they are moving too slowly so they are all stuck together. Try making them go up faster: `y-=50`, or separate them using, e.g. different initial x coordinates.

Comment: Making the increment bigger will not not, the problem lies in not clearing the last one of itsself. Thats what is wrong. Like the player moves so why wont the Elevator  :)

Comment: Making the speed faster helps you see the problem. The problem is what I wrote in my answer, that all your elevators are too close together, and they infinitely spawn.

Comment: But I only created one elevator?

Comment: No you are creating a new elevator on every animation frame: `Elevators.push(Ele1);` if you actually only want to create one, limit the length to 1.